# Change style of button during mouse hover event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I want to change the shape/style of button during mouse hover in  asp.net. Actually i want to make the button circular during mouse hover in asp.net.

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS solution?

Comment: @ginovva320 yes, exactly. i am using button in my default.asp file and i want to show it circular with mouse however event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you would do this with the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class:

```
a { /* define normal styles here */ }

a:hover { /* define hover styles here */ }
```

To achieve a circular button, you could use a graphic image.  Assuming you had a transparent PNG called circle.png in your images directory, you could do something like this:

```
a:hover {
  background: url('images/circle.png') no-repeat;
}
```

You could also set the border radius of the button to be one-half of the button height and width (which should be the same):

```
a:hover {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Sir, you are great, thumbs up for you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your element has a class of `button`, you could do the following:

```
.button:hover {
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

You'll have to tweak the radius to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Create two Images for button. Then implement this css.

```
.blueButton
{   
     background:url('../Images/btnBackground.png');          
     border:0;
}
.blueButton:hover
{  
   background:url('../Images/btnBackground_circular.png');   
}

<input id="Button1" type="button" class="blueButton" value="button" />
```